# Assigning names to certain ranges of values in vector based on their positions [R]

Tags: r, vector, names

I have a numeric vector which stores some values, for example:

```
vec <- sample(200:800, 20, replace = TRUE)
```

And an example two numeric variables indicating certain positions within this vector:

```
pos1 <- 6
pos2 <- 12
```

I would like to name all the values within the given vec which are < pos1 "front", values > pos2 "end" and values between those two coordinates "middle".

I am a beginner with R. I know how to do so with multiple lines of code, but I would be grateful for some more straightforward and better optimized solution.

Here is my code:

```
vec <- sample(200:800, 20, replace = TRUE)
positions <- 1:length(vec)
pos1 <- 6
pos2 <- 12

front <- positions[1:pos1-1]
middle <- positions[pos1:pos2]
end <- positions[(pos2+1):length(positions)]

segmentation <- c(rep("front", length(front)), rep("middle", length(middle)), rep("end", length(end)))
vec2 <- vec
vec2 <- setNames(segmentation, vec)
```

I know also how to do the trick by creating a df and then extracting named vec, but I would like to avoid this.

I would very much appreciate your help.

Comment: You can use `findInterval()` - e.g. `setNames(factor(findInterval(seq_along(vec), c(pos1, pos2), rightmost.closed = TRUE ), labels = c("front", "middle", "end")), vec)` or `cut()` - `setNames(cut(seq_along(vec), c(0,5, 12, Inf), labels = c("front", "middle", "end")), vec)`.

Comment: That's a perfectly valid way of doing it. It is logical, readable and does not contain redundant commands, and most importantly - does what you want. Writing understandable code is more important than chasing the shortest commands.

Comment: If the solution below solves your problem you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it

Comment: Hi @ramen, were you able to figure this out?

Comment: @Skaqqs yes, I used the ifelse approach, because it was convenient for my further manipulations, although findInterval() is also cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question you describe your problem with logic, so why not convert that logic in words to logic using an `ifelse()`:

```
# Create a toy vector with dummy names
vec <- sample(200:800, 20, replace = TRUE)
names(vec) <- 1:length(vec)

# Define criteria for naming
pos1 <- 6
pos2 <- 12

# Use logic to define names in toy vector
names(vec) <- ifelse(as.numeric(names(vec)) < pos1,
                     yes = "front",
                     no = ifelse(as.numeric(names(vec)) > pos2,
                                 yes = "back",
                                 no = "middle"))
vec
#>  front  front  front  front  front middle middle middle middle middle middle 
#>    762    205    469    484    653    491    505    432    783    345    366 
#> middle   back   back   back   back   back   back   back   back 
#>    664    498    706    248    547    317    695    749    225
Created on 2021-10-20 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In R, multiline code is not necessarily inefficient. Code is often optimized if code works with one subset of a vector at a time.

Here's the very plain way of doing what you want:

```
front <- seq_along(vec) < pos1
end <- seq_along(vec) > pos2
names(vec)[front] <- "front"
names(vec)[end] <- "end"
names(vec)[!front & !end] <- "middle"
```

It's also very fast. I compared it to Skaqq's nested `ifelse` expression, and a rewrite of the method you were trying with `rep`.

*In case you didn't know, if you give multiple values to `rep`'s `times` argument, then `rep(x, t)` will be equivalent to `c(rep(x[1], t[1]), rep(x[2], t[2]), ...)`.*

```
base_vector <- sample(200:800, 20, replace = TRUE)
names(base_vector) <- 1:length(base_vector)
pos1 <- 6
pos2 <- 12


microbenchmark(
  times = 1000,
  setup = {vec <- base_vector},
  # Single line using nested ifelse
  ifelse = {
    names(vec) <- ifelse(as.numeric(names(vec)) < pos1,
                         yes = "front",
                         no = ifelse(as.numeric(names(vec)) > pos2,
                                     yes = "end",
                                     no = "middle"))
  },
  # Multiple lines using vector subsetting
  multiline = {
    front <- seq_along(vec) < pos1
    end <- seq_along(vec) > pos2
    names(vec)[front] <- "front"
    names(vec)[end] <- "end"
    names(vec)[!front & !end] <- "middle"
  },
  # Slightly more efficient version of what you were doing
  rep = {
    fronts <- pos1 - 1
    middles <- pos2 - pos1 + 1
    ends <- length(vec) - pos2
    names(vec) <- rep(c("front", "middle", "end"), c(fronts, middles, ends))
  }
)
## Unit: microseconds
##       expr  min   lq    mean median    uq   max neval
##     ifelse 21.8 22.7 27.5472   23.2 25.20 172.2  1000
##  multiline  5.0  5.6  6.7580    5.9  7.40  26.3  1000
##        rep  2.4  2.7  3.4118    3.0  3.65  32.8  1000
```

So, from these 3, the `rep` version is fastest. Probably because `rep` is a "primitive" function. It calls directly to internal code, instead of hanging around in less-efficient R environments.

As for which one is most straightforward, that's your judgement. I personally prefer simple subsetting with logicals.